# d3js PieChart calculate arcs with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I try to create a pie Chart with d3js and typescript using React. I'm sticking to [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/pie-chart).

My data has this format:

```
const data: Data[] = [{name: "a", value: 5}, {name:"b", value: 3}, {name:"c", value: 2}];
```

This is the code I got so far:

```
import React, {useLayoutEffect, useRef} from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export type Data = { name: string; value: number; };
type PieChartProps = { size: number; data: Data[]; };

const PieChart: React.FC<PieChartProps> = ({size, data}) => {
    const ref = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);

    const pie = d3.pie<Data>().value(d => d.value);
    const arc = d3.arc<Data>().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(size / 2 - 1)
    const arcs = pie(data);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(ref.current)
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(arcs)
            .join("path")
            .attr("d", d => arc(d.data));
    });
    return <svg ref={ref} width={size} height={size}/>;
};

export default PieChart;
```

Unfortunately, the `arc` function seems to be not working properly as the resulting svg has no valid paths.

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <g>
        <path d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"></path>
        <path d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

In the example I used, they created the `path` element like this (abbreviated):

```
svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(arcs)
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

Using this, I get the error

```
Argument of type 'Arc<any, Data>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | SVGPathElement | null, PieArcDatum<Data>, string | ... 2 more ... | null>'.
    Types of parameters 'd' and 'datum' are incompatible.
    Property 'name' is missing in type 'PieArcDatum<Data>' but required in type 'Data'.
```

I suspect I did a mistake regarding the type of some variables or functions. **Can anyone tell me, what's going wrong here**?

Answer (score 3):

When you create an arc generator, you need to pass it the shape your data from the pie generator will take. In this case, it's your `Data` type wrapped in `PieArcDatum` --

```
type Data = { name: string; value: number; }; // shape of your data
const pie = d3.pie<Data>().value(d => d.value); // expects type Data, returns type <PieArcDatum<Data>>[]
const arc = d3.arc<PieArcDatum<Data>>().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(size / 2 - 1); // expects type <PieArcDatum<Data>> and returns string
```

This will create an arc generator that expects data in the structure you'll be passing to it via `d3.select`.

Comment: I believe I am having the same issue here, but your comment is not making sense much to me. Why do we have to delcare PieArcDatum wrapper? What should it do actually? can you give an example how it should look like? Thank you.